# overlay makes text unreadable -- where does it come from? Overlay face is "undefined face"

Tags: faces, doom, overlays

There is an overlay making parts of stack traces in my inferior python buffers very difficult to read:
[image]

I would like to change the coloring of the yellow part of line 42.  If I run M-x describe-char there it reveals that there is an overlay applied:

```
There is an overlay here:
 From 2370 to 2371
  evaporate            t
  face                 (:background "#F0DFAF")
  insert-behind-hooks  (ansi-color-freeze-overlay)
  modification-hooks   (ansi-color-freeze-overlay)
```

It's the combination of the foreground color and the background #F0DFAF that's problematic.  I'm not sure how to figure out where that background is coming from, or change it.  Enter over `(:background "#F0DFAF")` gives me:

`Face: :background   undefined face.`

The same sequence (M-x describe char, enter over an overlay face) elsewhere gives me an opportunity to customize the face.

I'm using Doom emacs and the zenburn theme, in case that's helpful.

**-------EDIT--------**

After reading the comment from @dalanicolai I'm getting somewhere.  If I run ansi-color-for-comint-mode-off, the stack trace shows the color escape sequences.  The one one causing the problem applies [43], which puts ansi-yellow in the background and leaves the foreground alone.  And for a dark-background theme that results in some light-colored text on a yellow background.  If I set the value for ansi-yellow to black:

```
(setq ansi-color-normal-colors-vector [ansi-color-black ansi-color-red ansi-color-green ansi-color-black ansi-color-blue ansi-color-magenta ansi-color-cyan ansi-color-white])
```

the yellow background becomes black and the stacktrace is readable.  Great!  But specifying a foreground color would be a better solution than telling it that yellow is now black.  So...  The question now becomes how to tell comint to use a different color for that situation.

I've dug around some in `ansi-color-process-output` and the functions it calls without much luck in connecting the treatment of comint output to actual colors.

What ended up working was customizing the face `ansi-color-yellow` locally for python-mode buffers.  I'm using doom emacs so this involved the `(after! python)` and `custom-theme-set-faces` doom macros.  Here's the relevant section of my config.el:

```
(after! python
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "jupyter"
        python-shell-interpreter-args "console --simple-prompt"
        python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters '("jupyter")
        lsp-file-watch-threshold 9999)
  (custom-theme-set-faces! '(doom-zenburn)
   `(ansi-color-yellow :background, "#F18C96")))
```

It's a hack, but I haven't seen it to affect anything other than error messages in inferior python buffer stack traces.  And for now I've spent about all the time I can spare on it.

Comment: It's apparently not a *named* face - it's just a drive-by face used in an overlay: an overlay that specifies a background color. I'd say bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you know which library is causing this you can maybe grep its files for that hex string. Hope that that code isn't just hard-wired...

Comment: Thanks.  Digging into the init, it seems to have to do with using jupyter-console for the REPL.  If I turn that off, the stacktrace in a plain python interpreter looks ok.  Still can't figure out where that color is set, though, or how to change it :(

Comment: I guess the output looks similar in a 'real' terminal. Also, I guess comint-mode uses `ansi-color.el` to 'filter' the colors, see `C-h v ansi-color-for-comint-mode`. So I guess you have to look into the `ansi-color-process-output` function.